# Algebraic substitutions not working?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, replacement

I have been trying to simplify this matrix
$$
    \left(
    \begin{array}{cc}
     \frac{1}{2} \left(-2 g \sqrt{1-\text{tauA}} \sqrt{1-\text{tauB}}+\text{mu} \text{tauA}+\text{mu} \text{tauB}+\text{omegaA} (1-\text{tauA})+\text{omegaB} (1-\text{tauB})\right) & 0 \\
     0 & \frac{1}{2} \left(2 \text{gprime} \sqrt{1-\text{tauA}} \sqrt{1-\text{tauB}}+\text{mu} \text{tauA}+\text{mu} \text{tauB}+\text{omegaA} (1-\text{tauA})+\text{omegaB} (1-\text{tauB})\right) \\
    \end{array}
    \right)
$$

using the following algebraic substitutions
$$
    omegaA - omegaA \cdot tauA + omegaB - omegaB \cdot tauB \to kappa
$$

$$ 
    2 \sqrt{(1 - tauA)(1 - tauB)} \to u
$$

I've tried a few options, but none of them seem to work. I've tried

```
theta /. {omegaA - omegaA*tauA + omegaB - omegaB*tauB -> kappa, 
  2* Sqrt[(1 - tauA)]*Sqrt[(1 - tauB)] -> u}
```

But this doesn't seem to do anything. I've also tried

```
Simplify[theta, {omegaA - omegaA*tauA + omegaB - omegaB*tauB == kappa,
   2 Sqrt[(1 - tauA) (1 - tauB)] == u}]
```

But for some reason this only works for substituting `kappa` and I get

```
{{1/2 (kappa - 2 g Sqrt[(-1 + tauA) (-1 + tauB)] + mu (tauA + tauB)), 
  0}, {0, 1/
   2 (kappa + 2 gprime Sqrt[(-1 + tauA) (-1 + tauB)] + 
     mu (tauA + tauB))}}
```

Can anyone explain why I'm having trouble with getting this to work? I know I could just replace the expressions by hand, but I'd really like to understand why this isn't working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: theta is nowhere defined.

Comment: Sorry, theta is the initial matrix

Comment: @LukasLang Yes! This was so helpful, thank you so much!